# "The archive passed validation with several warning" - where can i read them when I do not have an access to an email?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode7

I got that warning... but in my case I got access only to itunesconnect account, but I do not have an access to an email, where possible issues are reported to... Is it printed somewhere in logs, or to some file on my disc?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in your case it's actually *only one* warning and not "several".

Take a look at "Issue Navigator" <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> and "Report Navigator" <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> — they generally provide more detailed information about warnings and errors when available.

[image]

Warnings/Errors aren't emailed, so all of the available details should be logged within Xcode.

Comment: This is correct the warning is actually displayed juste beneath (API file too large)